# Threejs Scene not working in my project / THREE not defined

Tags: javascript, html, web, three.js

I wanted to create m first three js project and followed a tutorial.
But when my page loads no scene is showing up. The sscene should be completly black but the site is just white.

Chrome Browser Console:

three.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
main.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

My vs code workspace;

[image]

My html and js code:

```js
function main(){

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,1,1000);
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window,innerHeight);
    document.getElementById('webgl').appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
}

main();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Three js test</title>
        <style type="text/css">html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="webgl"></div>
        <script src="/lib/three.js"></script>
        <script src="./main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check browser console for errors and warnings.

Comment: three.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
main.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="lib/three.js"></script>
```

Maybe try removing the '/' from your three.js path?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up working with the live server extension of vs code and used the three.module.js.

It worked using this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).